# Java doc Annotation utf message

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, javadoc

JDK ： 17

Spring Boot:3.0.5

STS: 4.17.1.RELEASE

```
        @NotNull(message="用户名不可为空")
        @Length(min=6,max=24,message="用户名长度6～24字符")
        String username,
        @Length(min=8,max=64,message="密码为8～64字符")
        @NotNull(message="密码不可为空")
        String password,
        @NotNull(message="姓名不可为空")
        String name,
        String email,
        String inviteUUID
        ) {}
```

if we generate java doc for above code,
the message to transliteration to

record RegisterDTO(@NotNull(message="\u7528\u6237\u540d}\u7528\u6237\u540d\u4e0d\u53ef\u4e3a\u7a7a") @Length(min=6,max=24,message="\u7528\u6237\u540d\u957f\u5ea66\uff5e24\u5b57\u7b26") String username, @Length(min=8,max=64,message="\u5bc6\u7801\u4e3a8\uff5e64\u5b57\u7b26") @NotNull(message="\u5bc6\u7801\u4e0d\u53ef\u4e3a\u7a7a") String password,
@NotNull(message="\u59d3\u540d\u4e0d\u53ef\u4e3a\u7a7a") String name, String email,
String inviteUUID)

How to display the unicode character, not the transliteration in java doc

Comment: Seems like a problem with the javadoc generator. In any case, how about writing these in English instead? Assuming this is spring, you can do the localisation in a .properties file.

Comment: What version of Java are you using.  This might be https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8203176 ... which is fixed in Java 11.

Comment: @StephenC I can reproduce in Java 17. That bug is only for `@code` blocks it seems.

Comment: OK ... so this is could be a previously unreported bug.